# Trying to ad content after input-field with after()

Tags: jquery, drupal

after the input field, i would like to add an asterisk:

`<input class="required">`

with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".required").after("*");
});
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/t2mLfeks/

Comment: Check your console for errors elsewhere in your code; there is no reason that the code in the question shouldn't work.

Comment: In addition to what @RoryMcCrossan said, I would temporarily add `alert("JS loaded");` to your code to make sure that the JS is being properly included. If you reload the page and don't see an alert box, then it's not being included properly.

Comment: `(function($) { YOUR CODE HERE })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".required").after("*");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Check that you put your code inside a closure and map jQuery to the `$` shortcut. You can read more about it here: [Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213)

Comment: This was actually a rewrite of @Clive's comment to the OP, which basically answers the question, I think.